# Conversión de cadena de texto a FLOAT usando ATOF en lenguaje C para lectura de fichero

Tags: c, dev-c++

soy estudiante y tengo un problema con mi código, tengo un fichero con unos valores por ej: 218,90 , estos están declarados como cadena de caracteres en un TXT y necesito convertirlos a float , el código lo tengo listo y sé que debo usar este código, la idea es que cuando el bucle while vaya leyendo linea por linea y encuentre una coma ',' la convierta a un punto y luego ya convertido en punto el ATOF haga lo suyo y convierta el texto en FLOAT

```
    for(int i= 0; linea[i] < '\0' ; i++){
        if(linea[i] == ','){
        linea[i] = '.';
        }}
```

pero no se bien donde poner el código.

mi código principal es este:

```
FILE *ficheroProductosLectura;
ficheroProductosLectura = fopen("ficheroProductos.txt", "r");
char linea1[100];
struct productos datos1;
        
int contadorlineas = 0;

while((fgets(linea, 100, ficheroProductosLectura)) != NULL) {
    if(contadorlineas %4 == 0) {
        strtok(linea, "\n"); /*STRTOK ---> va a eliminar una línea especificamente el 
 espacio \n */
        strcpy(datos1.nombre, linea); /* STRCPY ---> va a copiar y guardando el 
contenido de linea en la variable datos1.nombre*/   
            
        printf("\nNombre: %s\n\t", datos1.nombre);  
            
    } else if(contadorlineas %4 == 1) {
        strtok(linea, "\n");
        strcpy(datos1.marca, linea);
    
        printf("\nMarca: %s\n\t", datos1.marca);
    } else if(contadorlineas %4 == 2) {
        strtok(linea, "\n");
    int codigo = atoi(linea); /* --- > ATOI convierte una cadena en enteros*/
        datos1.codigo = codigo;
        printf("\nCodigo: %d\n\t", datos1.codigo);
    } else if (contadorlineas %4 == 3) {
    strtok(linea, "\n");
     float precio = atof(linea); /*ATOF convierte una cadena en float, EN PRECIO se va 
    almacenar el atof*/  
        
        printf("\nPrecio: %.2f  \n\t", datos1.precio);
    }
    contadorlineas++;    
    }   
  fclose(ficheroProductosLectura);
```

Comment: Porque no sabes?  Tienes una idea de donde va?  O donde lo pondrias tu?

Comment: yo lo pondria dentro del while antes del if , he probado pero no funciona :( , tambien probe ponerlo fuera y tampoco funciona :( , no se si sera eso o hay algo mas que no estoy viendo...

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Ninguno… simplemente no lee el bucle while entonces no se si estoy poniendo mal el if dentro del while o donde debe ir porque he probado dentro y fuera del while y no lo pilla …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sabes dónde poner el código porque no sigues algunas buenas prácticas de programación que te pueden ayudar a diseñarlo, como por ejemplo el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica).

Separa tu código en elementos funcionales individuales:

- Leer línea.
- Procesar línea.
- Convertir número.

Una vez hecho, el código será más fácil de entender y más fácil de trabajar:

```c
int leer_linea(FILE *f, char *buffer)
{
    if (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, f) != NULL)
    {
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        buffer[len - 1] = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void procesar_linea(char *buffer)
{
    for (char *c = buffer, *e = buffer + BUFFER_SIZE; *c && (c != e); ++c)
    {
        if (*c == ',')
        {
            *c = '.';
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (f)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {};
        while (leer_linea(f, buffer))
        {
            procesar_linea(buffer);
            printf("El numero leido es %06f\n", atof(buffer));
        }

        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJRa9swFIWfrV9x67LGTtTgrFu3kWUPgwQKYQ8tfWk3jCtfJRqOFWSlLRT/9uxKkYvXMPamcyRdffceifOVEPv9qapFtSsRvja2VHq8/sb6llH16q1XVurBeey0RKlqhO@3i8X8Or@5upvDJMsYe9SqBGGwMHlhxFo96rzEHH/jZlvpJGUvLFpcLecwlDADqbdYJ7HFxo7ts405xE9xOmWRkpDIlEV0OpJbIrEykZxEFE/4@4sPP@vYi4@X/NPnTnzJaI@EKxBJUekGqQiJlrWMUQ2oEE1eEXeRBAgOYl0YGD7spETj8fzbK7RNcjB5v0kOMoWTGfy4XS4D36FwTe3QzGgRrnmKw/LebZ/D5BedyZxt0O5MDRPPxjpJW20Y4NZogU3RwR4xSm0guIKKdqBDfBUw6mNP3bmzM7rj4DGdwmgkOn7q11WZwYAPyPNm5OsOxgOHGwDdsu1Nc1OoOnG4HunfmU/ZfzI3R5n71sLwem24Ab60juNprSqEpBcoRRkG9NrDmyn2conCn4rnFdS7DRpNEapSAzbwLruU9Is4FFbL7lJ6aP7oY/0V3n7/Bw)</kbd>.

Comment: JUTSU de invocacion , maestro de las tijera y el origami invoco al maestro de papel con alas plumiferas PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Invocación -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol